# Different CalendarID between Outlook.MAPIFolder and the Office 365 API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

Currently, I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder  in Outlook app, and use this API `https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars` in Office 365 api to get CalendarID.

But there is different CalendarID in result. Why did have this difference?

Answer (score 0):

These are different API's eg one is MAPI and one is REST so they have different Id formats. You can use the Graph API (or EWS) to translate the Id between formats https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-translateexchangeids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http . You could also just get the PR_EntryId extended property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/extended-properties-rest-operations using the REST API which should match whatever CalendarId you getting from MAPI.